# How to remove the extra right margin/space in MUI grid?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

The MUI grid example below seems to create an extra space to the right of the grid and makes it look like the grid is not occupying the whole space that is available on the page.

[image: show extra space]

I have tried to change/remove the following margin values but it doesn't help:

```
.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-1 {
    width: calc(100% + 8px);
    margin: -4px;
}
```

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-with-background-color-xx89y?file=/demo.js:0-1236)

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
}));

export default function NestedGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function FormRow() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For me, I had a `width='100%'` on my grid container. Once I removed that, it worked as expected.

Comment: Fixed here: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#negative-margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra space on the right isn't caused by the styles you included in your question, it is caused by the default `justify-content` of `flex-start` for the outermost Grid. If you specify `justify="center"` on the outermost Grid then the contents of the Grid will be centered.

[image: Show centered Grid]

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
}));

export default function NestedGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function FormRow() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={1} justify="center">
        <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Grid centering]

Related resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#justify-content

Comment: I have specified `justify="center"` already in the outer most Grid, but still getting spacing as mentioned in the question. Any idea?

Comment: @AyeshWeerasinghe What version of Material-UI are you using?

Comment: I'm using `"^4.9.13"`

Comment: @AyeshWeerasinghe I recommend creating your own question where you can share the details of your problem including the code to reproduce it. Provide a link to this question if you think it provides useful context.

Answer (score 0):

removing the space by `justify="center"` didn't work for me... but I guess this issue is universal and MUI people solved it by releasing version-2 of Grid [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid2/#fluid-grids). I'm pretty sure you're looking for something of that kind known as Fluid Grid... so yeah, we have no more unnecessary padding or margin issues.

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';
 
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid xs={4}>Box 1</Grid>
  <Grid xs={4}>Box 2</Grid>
  <Grid xs={4}>Box 3</Grid>
</Grid>;
```

this is how you could use it :)